# Is it possible to use Logmein to connect to a sleeping (Mac) computer on a wireless network?

Tags: macos, mac, wake-on-lan, logmein

I'm using logmein to access my Mac.

So I have the local logmein app running on my MacBook Pro, which is on my home wireless network.  I access it either from the website (www.logmein.com) or the Logmein Ignition Apps on the iphone or ipad.

My problem is that I have to set my MacBook Pro to not sleep at all when plugged in to make this a practical solution, because logmein cant seem to wake it up.  I did change the settings in System Preferences to allow "Wake from Lan", but it seems like this won't work with a a Wifi connection.  Am I missing anything?

Assuming I'm not, is it bad for my computer to basically leave it running and not asleep most of the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the more recent models of MacBook Pro support Wake on Wireless when running Snow Leopard. In System Preferences > Energy Saver, you'd see a checkbox called "Wake for AirPort network access" if your system supported it.

Wake on Wireless is a little trickier to get working right because many third-party wireless routers don't support 802.11 powersave mode properly. Also, Apple limited Wake on Wireless support to only work when your MacBook is plugged into its AC power adaptor, so that your machine doesn't drain its battery extra fast by keeping your wireless connection alive all the time your machine is sleeping.

Apple has a support knowledge base article on the subject. The article covers some additional technologies like the Bonjour Sleep Proxy Service, but you can ignore those parts that don't apply to your situation and concentrate on the parts about Wake on Wireless specifically. [Mac OS X v10.6: About Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774).

Apple's whole end-to-end service is pretty neat, the way MobileMe's Back To My Mac feature integrates with Bonjour Sleep Proxy Service running on modern Apple AirPort base stations, which integrates with the Bonjour Sleep Proxy client and Wake-on-LAN / Wake-on-Wireless support on suitable Snow Leopard Macs.